# Openfire : unable to conversate with people from other servers

Tags: xmpp, openfire

I'm a bit stuck ; I recently upgraded Openfire on my server and am now using the version 3.7.0

Even though I had no problem before and had not had to change any option, I'm now unable, when connected on this server, to conversate with people from other servers, whatever the other server is. I can, though, talk with the only friend I have on MY server.

I guess it has to do with the Server Settings, but I have no clue which one I should touch and I don't want to break anything.

The daemon is running on Debian 6.0.1, on which I'm not using a firewall.

What should I try ? Could it have something to do with SSL certificates ? (I'm asking this last question because everytime I connect I get :

[12:18:02] SSL status:1

[12:18:02] Certificate is not trusted!)

Here is the complete error log : http://paste2.org/p/1473121

... and the warn log : [http://paste2.org/p/1473123](http://paste2.org/p/1473121)

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

From the log you have showed it looks like the upgrade is messed up.
(re)Read the documentation regarding the upgrade or do a clean install.

On one hand you have broken sql schema and maybe your server cannot connect to remote server (again according to the logs).

**EDIT**:

Are you sure your server can connect other hosts?

- dns is working?
- outgoing connections are not firewalled?

**EDIT2**:

You should open

```
5269 TCP     XMPP server connection (RFC 3920)        Official
```

too.
Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452161/which-ports-does-xmpp-uses for more info.

Comment: I've tried to do a full reinstallation but it didn't change anything. Whenever I try reaching a remote server (using mcabber client for example) I get a "Received error packet [remote-server-not-found]" error.

Comment: Answer to you edit : I guess DNS is working since all my websites are working, also I can ping or nslookup any server.

nmap tells me that ports that should be open are (5222 and 7777)

Comment: Answer to edit2 : Too late, I just migrated to ejabberd. Sorry for that and thank you for your help, I'll keep this in case I use Openfire again.